# Magento 2 Created a custom product Attribute of drop down yes or no

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute

I have created a custom attribute in magento 2 for product using a source Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean

Here is the code

```
     if(!$eavSetup->getAttributeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'purchase_unit')) {
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'purchase_unit',
            [
                'group' => 'Rocket',
                'type' => 'int',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Purchase Unit', /* lablel of your attribute*/
                'input' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                /*Scope of your attribute */
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '0',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false
            ]
        );
    }
```

The attribute is getting created and also displays in product page. The issue is it displays YES as default value which is 1. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just have options Yes/No. Replacing `'input' => 'select'` with `'input' => 'boolean'` will solve your problem.

Hope it was helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Solved using a different source.